# How to use a loop (for) to download.file and write.csv using names from a list in R

Tags: r, loops, csv, for-loop

So i've got to write.csv's for each downloaded files, with the currencies from a bunch a countries, from the web. And i wanted it to be saved using their ticks.

So i did,

```
codigos = list("JPY", "RUB","SGD","BRL","INR","THB","GBP","EUR","CHF")

for (i in 1:9){

url1 = 'http://www.exchangerates.org.uk/'
url2='-USD-exchange-rate-history-full.html'

codigos = list("JPY", "RUB","SGD","BRL","INR","THB","GBP","EUR","CHF")
codigo = codigos[i]

url <- paste(url1, codigo, url2, sep = "")



download.file(url, destfile='codigo.html')


dados <- readHTMLTable('codigo.html')

write.csv(dados, file="codigo.csv")


}
```

although it can read each of the url's altered by the loop, it can't download them, nor save the csv's individually. During the process i can see each of them being "saved" in a file named codigo.html and in the very end i get a codigo.html and a codigo.csv with the last country of the list.

Comment: What do you mean "it can't download them, nor save the csv"? Are you getting an error? Does the code run fine? If you run outside a loop the the variables get the values you expect?

Comment: the code runs fine, but it doesn't get me each file for each country as i need, it gets me a file for the very last country of the list, with the name codigos.csv instead of their tick as needed...

Comment: Are you talking about the `codigo.csv` file? You never seem to change the file name so you keep writing over the same file every time. That might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're saving everything to the same filename.  Each pass through the loop will overwrite the prior contents entirely.

Note also that readHTMLTable will take a URL.  So perhaps something like this is in order:

```
for (i in 1:9){

    url1 = 'http://www.exchangerates.org.uk/'
    url2='-USD-exchange-rate-history-full.html'

    cod = codigos[i]

    url <- paste(url1, cod, url2, sep = "")

    dados <- readHTMLTable(url)

    # Create a unique name for each file
    filename <- paste(cod, 'csv', sep='.')
    write.csv(dados, file=filename)
}
```

Instead of creating csv files on disk, you might be better off using a list to hold the data, so you can manipulate the list:

```
url1 <- 'http://www.exchangerates.org.uk/'
url2 <- '-USD-exchange-rate-history-full.html'

l <- lapply(codigos
            , function(i) readHTMLTable(paste0(url1, i, url2))
            )
names(l) <- codigos
```

Comment: @user3693474 If it worked, you should consider pressing the green checkmark to accept the answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

a) in your loop "url <- ..." line should go before "download.file(url ...)"

```
url <- paste(url1, cod, url2, sep = "")
download.file(url, destfile='cod.html')
```

b) in your line "write.csv(url, file=nome)" , nome must be between "

```
write.csv(url, file= "nome")
```